# If multiple instances of (different versions of) apache are running, how to httpd -V for each one?

Tags: apache, httpd.conf

'httpd -V' returns various properties (e.g. -D HTTPD_ROOT and -D SERVER_CONFIG_FILE) for an instance of the apache server.

Say a host is running multiple instances of apache, each potentially from different locations, different versions, etc. In that case, 'httpd -V' probably displays information for one instance at random.

How can one get the output for all the apache instances running on the host (i.e. all these properties for each instance of the httpd process)?

For example, if the host is running an apache 2.4.11 instance and a 2.4.12 instance, what command will output a set of properties for each of these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use the path to where the binary is

```
/path/to/httpd -V
```